# Connecting to SQL Local Database using ConfigurationManager ASP.NET/C#

Tags: asp.net, mysql, visual-studio

I've been trying to connect to my local database created in Visual Studio Professional using SQL Commands...

I am trying to run my code but am faced with the following error complaining about my 'ConnectionString' (see this image)

The error is saying that "NullReferendException was unhandled by user code. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Error]

I can't get this database connected to my form for the life of me.

Here are my configuration settings found in web.config

[image: web.config]

Any help with getting my connection going with the local database would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to tweek my connection for two days and still stuck at the issue with the .ConnectionString

///////////////////////////////

UPDATE - 10:55 8/2

After switching my conn settings to: 
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

I am now faced with this error complaining about the Exception:

[image]

Comment: You are calling Database1 where you need to put "ConnectionString" According to your settings.

Comment: I know but when I change this to "ConnectionString" i am also presented with the same error.

Comment: In your Web.config file What is it set to under "providerName" ?

Comment: providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"

I switched my conn settings to:  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);     which kinda works but now im getting an error that says //// "SQLException was unhandled by User Code"... its complaining about my conn.Open() exception. I updated my question with the screenshot of this error.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but I'd think that `System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0` is designed specifically for Sql Server Compact and not MySQL.  You'll need a provider for MySQL.  Here's reference that might be useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Darn... ok so I need to download a MySQL client and manage my future DB's within it?

Comment: Well if you really want to connect to MySQL you can simply download and install the ADO.NET for it at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ , then just follow it's documentation.  If it's not necessary to connect to MySQL you can just set up your databases in the SQL Server Compact that appears to be installed by default and use the link from my previous comment.

Comment: This download link is better for Visual Studio integration with MySQL  http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html

Comment: Ok giving it a try! Hopefully this is easy to get integrated quickly

Comment: If you already have MySQL installed then be careful not to overwrite it.  The best bet would be to install the latest version then migrate your tables over from your old version.  However I've never done this so not sure how easy it would be.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a connection string named `Database1`, it's named `ConnectionString`. Change your code to `ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"]`.

**UPDATE:** looks like the OP already fixed that.

That error tends to indicate that your `SQLEXPRESS` instance isn't up and running. Make sure the services are started and the server is running.